# Consider a sequence $(a_n )$ of positive numbers satisfying the given condition

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$a_n\cdot a_{n+2} ≤ a_{n+1}^2$. Then $a_n$ is a:

(a)  convergent sequence if $a_1≠ 2a_2$

(b)  monotonically increasing sequence if $a_1≠ 2a_2$

(c)  convergent sequence if $a_1=2a_2$

(d)  monotonically increasing sequence if $a_1= 2a_2$

How do I derive a relation between $a_1$ and $a_2$?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the question.  It is _not_ asking you to derive a relationship between $a_1$ and $a_2$.  Instead, it is asking you to derive a property of the sequence _from_ a relationship between $a_1$ and $a_2$.

Comment: I would suggest trying a few combinations of $a_1$ and $a_2$ in situations like this. It helps get an idea of what might go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this as

$$\frac{a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}} \leq \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$

The ratio between consecutive terms is always nonincreasing. By the ratio lemma, convergence is guaranteed if the first ratio $a_2/a_1$ is less than $1$.

Moreover, if the first ratio is $\leq 1$, then the sequence must be monotonically decreasing.

Comment: Didn't you get the inequality wrong?

Comment: Fixed. Im on mobile so I cant write my answer and see the question at the same time

Comment: Thanks this makes it clear! So I'll go with option (c) then?

Comment: Yes in option (c) ${\frac{a_2}{a_1}}$ = $(1/2)$